# Ayuda con ejercicio de array en php

Tags: php, array, bucle-for

Algo estoy haciendo mal, hay que rellenar el array $resultado con los números del 0 al 10. Los mismos deben agregarse en el array automáticamente en las posiciones... del 0 al 10.

```
function bucles() {
    $resultado = [];

          for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
           $resultado = [i];
    }


    return $resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos para que te funcion puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
function bucleFor(){
    $numeros = array();
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
        $numeros[]= $i;  
    }
    return $numeros;
}
print_r(bucleFor());
```

Tu resultado lo obtendrias de la siguiente manera:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
)
```

Fijate que para que funcione debes asignarle al array el valor de tu ciclo for:

```
$numeros[]= $i;
```

dado que **$numeros** es tu array y "**$i**" es tu variable del ciclo for.

espero te ayude y suerte..!!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error de sintaxis.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
function bucles() {
    $resultado = [];

    for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
       $resultado[] = $i;
    }

    return $resultado;
}
```